# Using my ISerializable implementation instead of DataContractSerializer

Tags: wcf

My WCF client and server exchange objects whose types are defined on a class library shared by both, the server and the client. These objects implement custom serialization via ISerializable. However, my custom serialization is not being used. DataContractSerializer is being used, instead.  How do I force my custom serialization to be used?

The reason why I need to use my own serialization is because I do trasfer some big object graphs and my serialization algorithm does a good job in compressing/speeding up things.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: To learn why it's preferred that you not start your titles with "WCF - " and such.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding the correct attributes to your wcf contact.

See: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/ for details.

If this does not help, show some code of how you have told the wcf contract that it should use the custom serializer.